# The robot do not move even there is a goal for it using navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, explore, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I am using the explore stage(wiki.ros.org/explore) and motified it with multi-robots.
(1)When I run it I always find that when the robot's goal is very far and  behand the robot ,I will not move.
(2)Also, the robot always goes into the  inflation area and do not move for the goal, I have read the navigation guide but maybe I can't understand some of them ,So I want to find some help here for the reason why it do not move
this is the details:         docs.google.com/drawings/d/17D6umDL43akGIcRJbAAy27SnUKy9LlGorETI3w04nWY/edit?usp=sharing

```
  controller_frequency: 10.0
  TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  transform_tolerance: 0.3
  world_model: costmap

  acc_lim_x: 0.5
  acc_lim_y: 0.5
  acc_lim_th: 1.0
  max_vel_x: 0.65
  min_vel_x: 0.10
  max_rotational_vel: 2.5
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.001
  escape_vel: -0.1
  holonomic_robot: false
  #y_vels: [-0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3]

  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.05
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.15
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false

  sim_time: 2.7
  sim_granularity: 0.05
  vx_samples: 8
  vtheta_samples: 20

  meter_scoring: true
  occdist_scale: 0.01
  heading_lookahead: 0.325
  heading_scoring: false
  heading_scoring_timestep: 0.8
  dwa: true

  oscillation_reset_dist: 0.1

  goal_distance_bias: 0.05 #0.4
  path_distance_bias: 0.07 #0.3
  escape_reset_dist: 0.15
  escape_reset_theta: 0.30
  simple_attractor: false`
```

and the costmap_common

```
 map_type: costmap
transform_tolerance: 0.3
obstacle_range: 7.9
max_obstacle_height: 2.0
raytrace_range: 7.9

robot_radius: 0.15 #0.10  
inflation_radius: 0.5 #0.12

cost_scaling_factor: 15.0
lethal_cost_threshold: 100
track_unknown_space: true
```

Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153126/the-robot-do-not-move-even-there-is-a-goal-for-it-using-navigation/) by [physicsex](https://answers.ros.org/users/12066/physicsex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-15**:
@physicsex; Did you execute `roslaunch explore_stage explore_slam.launch`? As this launch file includes `gmapping`, robot seems to make a map of a world. As `explore.launch` doesn't include a kind of like amcl, the robot doesn't know where it is. I think so.

**Comment by [physicsex](https://answers.ros.org/users/12066/physicsex/) on 2014-04-17**:
Thank you!  But I think it knows where it is because it can go for a goal sometimes but if the goal is a little far away  I can't go for it and just stand there ,also sometimes it just go around. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible that goal-points are set somewhere near or within unknown space? Like when you set a point behind you which had previously not been seen and therefore undiscovered?

The trajectory planner is not able to navigate to a goal which is outside the free space. Use RVIZ to see the already known and the unknown space!
Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [dneuhold](https://answers.ros.org/users/5295/dneuhold/) with karma: 205 on 2014-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [physicsex](https://answers.ros.org/users/12066/physicsex/) on 2014-04-15**:
Do you mean that the goal which I set is in the unknown space? I have set that the goal should be in the free space and in the RVIZ I can't find any difficult to plan it ,please look at the picture https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/17D6umDL43akGIcRJbAAy27SnUKy9LlGorETI3w04nWY/edit?usp=sharing

**Comment by [dneuhold](https://answers.ros.org/users/5295/dneuhold/) on 2014-04-23**:
is your trajectory planner planning a path to the goal? in your figure it seems like the planner stops at some position. Try to increase the sim_time in your base_local_planner file.